# Assemble: register handlebar helper function

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine, assemble, grunt-assemble

I'm using [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) 0.4.17 which has bundled handlebar 1.3.0.
I'm trying to add a custom handlebar helper as documented [here](http://assemble.io/docs/Custom-Helpers.html).

So I added this to my Gruntfile (at the bottom of the file, outside of `module.exports = function(grunt) {`)

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports.asdf = function (str)  {  return 'asdf here!'; };
```

And added this to
**index.hbs**

```
{{#asdf}}
  bobo
{{/asdf}}
```

And I would suggest that `asdf here!` would show up in the generated html, but it does not, instead only a blank line is printed. I also tried the `module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options)` method, but this didn't work as well. Do I need to add something else to add this handlebar helper?

I'm new to Assemble and grunt and handlebar, so I might just be missing the obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The helpers should be declared in another file and added to the `helpers` option in your assemble target:

my-helper.js

```
module.exports.asdf = function (str) { return 'asdf here!'; };
```

Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
  assemble: {
    options: {
      helpers: ['./my-helper.js']
    },
    someTarget: {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: indeed, the helpers-option was missing, IMO this part is completely missing in [this docs page](http://assemble.io/docs/Custom-Helpers.html), all it has is a link to [options.helpers](http://assemble.io/docs/options-helpers.html) with no info that this actually needs to be added.

Comment: You're right. The docs aren't the best, but we're working on cleaning them up. If you have a good idea on explaining the configuration from you're experience, please consider submitting a pull request so we can improve the docs for others.